# Locating a node in a CompilationUnitSyntax AND SemanticModel

Tags: c#, roslyn

When working with Roslyn, I will often have a node that is in the CompilationUnitSyntax but not the SemanticModel or vice-versa.  (Or I can only pull the nodes out with operations of one or the other--For example if you need type info from a semantic model, the node querying on has to exist in the SemanticModel's tree)

I can see why they did it for immutability and all that, but how the heck do you consistently go back and find the same token from one tree to another??  If you modify either tree, you have to retrieve the node you were working with somehow.  What's the best way to do it????

Comment: I'm not sure I completely understand your question (maybe an example would help), but have you looked at annotations? They can be used to keep track of some node while the tree changes.

Comment: Bingo that's what I need.  Yeeesh.  It's tough to ask a question about Roslyn because the "What are you ACTUALLY trying to do?" answer is so damn long.  If you rewrite your question as a main answer I will mark it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to keep track of a single syntax node while you're changing the tree, you can use `SyntaxAnnotation`.

To use it, create a new `SyntaxAnnotation` (or a custom derived type, if you need to keep some additional information with that annotation) and then add it to a node by calling `annotation.AddAnnotationTo(node)` or `node.WithAdditionalAnnotations(annotation)`. Keep in mind that the node is still immutable, so you need to replace the original one with the annotated one in the tree.

Then, after you perform some modifications to the tree, you can get the annotated node back by using something like `parentNode.GetAnnotatedNodesAndTokens(annotation).Single().AsNode()`. (You can also get all nodes annotated by a specific derived type of annotation by `parentNode.GetAnnotatedNodesAndTokens(typeof(CustomAnnotationType))`.)

Comment: My mistake this didn't actually help me.  I thought I could add annotations to a existing tree's nodes but no dice.  I'm working with a CompilationUnitSyntax and its descendant nodes and a SemanticModel.SyntaxTree.GetRoot set of nodes because.  My real problem is the impedence mismatch here.  I'm dealing with 2 sets of nodes to get different information from each; then if I modify anything I have to recreate both and re-find my nodes in both.  Is there any better way?  It's getting really complex and crufty

Comment: How come they are two different sets of nodes? Why can't you work just with one of them?

Comment: How could you possibly use SemanticModel.GetTypeInfo on a CompilationUnitSyntax' tree node?  Getting type info from a CompilationUnitSyntax tree doesn't seem possible.  I need the ConvertedType of a SimpleLambdaExpressionSyntaxNode.

Comment: Let me ask another way.  Show me how to get the type of a SimpleLambdaExpression from a CompilationUnitSyntax.  That's what I'm REALLY trying to do :)  I maintain a SemanticModel and its tree for type information only.  If there's a better way, I would be so grateful to hear one.

Comment: Well, what you should do is to have a `SyntaxTree` that contains your code and every time you change it, recreate your `Compilation` and `SemanticModel` from it. That way, you can get the type of a `SimpleLambdaExpressionSyntax` that you found in your `SyntaxTree`. I don't understand why would you need to maintain two trees separately.

Comment: Annotations turned out to be what I needed.  I was a bit confused until I managed to get them to work.  Now it is not a pain to call on the Semantic model for information while you work with the CompilationUnitSyntax.  Thanks!